# Correct way to ask for a one day leave

Tags: work-environment, leave-of-absence

I am working as a trainee and am given no paid leaves, but due to some reason I got to take a leave for a day, I don't want to disclose the reason to the employer. Who do I email, the HR or my direct supervisor? Should the email be on that day or a day in advance? I am doubtful whether the content should be about seeking a leave or informing I would be on leave. Please suggest me on these two questions, thanks.

Comment: "Should the email be on that day or a day in advance?" How about ASAP?

Comment: You can *ask* who to notify

Comment: Hey user1502, welcome to The Workplace SE. Take a look at the [help/on-topic], as well as [ask]. These resources will help you formulate your questions so they're less likely to be closed. You can also edit your on-hold posts to make them fit our format, and they'll get bumped to the top of the main page for review. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Ask your supervisor, imagine if HR would be notified of every employee that has to take the day off. Your supervisor will contact HR if it's a company where it's required to be notified (unlikely, it's usually just logged electronically).

Ask now, asking on the same day or the day before is more likely to end up with a "no" because plans have been made and or your supervisor does not think that you respect your workplace's time by notifying in advance, especially if you knew for a long time that you needed the day off.

It's rather simple, tell him(her) that you really need to take the day off, if possible, it's usually not a problem, especially since you're the one loosing a one day of pay but not the company. Consider explaining what's going on if asked, your supervisor is someone who you should be able to trust with explaining of your absence, but just saying that it's about personal matters should cover it but it might make things look worse than they are. Just consider it.

Answer (score 2):

> Who do I email, the HR or my direct supervisor?

If you have a contract it may state their policy on request/notification of absence so check that first.

If not I would suggest that you inform them both as HR may need to know for administrative reasons and your supervisor is the one who will be affected by you not being able to work that day. Perhaps email your supervisor and CC HR.

> Should the email be on that day or a day in advance?

You should let them know as soon as possible. The only time it is acceptable to notify an employer of an absence so late is if you are ill or something else unexpected has happened that prevents you from coming in (e.g. death of a close family member.)

> I am doubtful whether the content should be about seeking a leave or informing I would be on leave.

This depends partly on your reasons for missing work that day. If it is something you absolutely *must* do or would do regardless of their answer then it should be more informative. Otherwise it should be more for asking permission.

Given that you do not want to disclose the reason for your absence you should be careful how you word the communications. For example "due to personal family reasons that I would rather not disclose". Hopefully your employer will be sympathetic and not press you for more information.